# Guice: Avoid lazy injection

Tags: guice

I have a class Cache which is quite expensive to create, but after that is set as a singleton and injected into my service layer.

```
@Override
protected void configure() {            
    bind(Cache.class).in(Singleton.class);

    bind(Service.class).to(ServiceImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);      
}

@Inject
    public ServiceImpl(Cache cache){
        this.cache = cache;
    }

public Cache(){
//Expensive stuff
}
```

My problem is it seems public() in Cache only executes when I'm trying to access one of its methods

Can I somehow make the object get constructed on server startup instead?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, bind it using [`.asEagerSingleton()`](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes#eager-singletons):

```
bind(Service.class).to(ServiceImpl.class).asEagerSingleton();
```

Note that according to that link, `Guice` will eagerly create all `Singleton`s if being run in the `PRODUCTION` stage (it lazily creates them in the `DEVELOPMENT` stage for faster test deployment).  You can specify the `Stage` when creating the `Injector`:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(Stage.PRODUCTION, new MyModule());
```

Comment: awesome, I had no idea on how to apply the Stage. Thanks for updating the answer